# Cannot cast from 'TFmxChildrenList' to 'TRectangle *'

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I'm new to using C++ Builder so apologies if I'm making any rudimentary mistakes.

I have drawn out a TLayout named 'Collection' with a 5x5 grid of TRectangles within it. The cells are named like so "CellXY".
I presumed it might be easier to draw these out on the Form rather than instantiating them with code, now I'm thinking otherwise, but I would still like to solve the problem this way to better my understanding.

I'm trying to write a method which will return a pointer to a TRectangle whose name contains the coordinates passed to the method.

Currently, I'm trying to do this by iterating through the children of the TLayout Collection:

```
TRectangle* __fastcall TForm2::getCellRectangleFromCoordinate(int X, int Y){
    TRectangle* targetCell = NULL;
    char targetCellName[6];
    sprintf(targetCellName, "Cell%i%i", X, Y);
    for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < Collection->ChildrenCount; ++cIndex)
    {
        TRectangle* cellRect = (TRectangle*) Collection->Children[cIndex]; // Error Here
        string cellName = cellRect->Name;
        if (targetCellName == cellName) {
            targetCell = cellRect;
            break;
        }
    }
    return targetCell;
}
```

But I am given an error reading:

```
E2031 Cannot cast from 'TFmxChildrenList' to 'TRectangle *'
```

If anyone could help, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Children`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TFmxObject.Children) property is a pointer to a class type ([`TFmxChildrenList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Types.TFmxChildrenList)) that internally holds an array of objects.  `Children` is not the actual array itself, like you are trying to treat it as.

`Children[cIndex]` is using pointer arithmetic, which is not what you want in this situation.  You need to use the `Children->Items[]` sub-property instead, by changing this statement:

```
Collection->Children[cIndex]
```

To either this:

```
Collection->Children->Items[cIndex]
```

Or this:

```
(*(Collection->Children))[cIndex]
```